# How to escape a pipe char in a code statement in a markdown table?

Tags: github, escaping, pipe, markdown

On GitHub I want to build a table containing pieces of code in Markdown. It works fine except when I put a pipe char (i.e. | ) between the backtick (i.e. ` ) chars.

Here is what I want:

```
      a     |  r  
------------|-----
 `a += x;`  |  r1
 `a |= y;`  |  r2
```

The problem is that the vertical bar in the code statement of the second line is interpreted as a column delimiter. Then the table rendering looks pretty ugly. How could I avoid that?

Note that I already tried to use the `&#124;` HTML code, but it produces `a &#124;= y;`.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

> As of March 2017 using escaped pipes is much easier: `\|` See other answers.

If you remove the backticks (**`**), using the `&#124;` hack works

```
      a     |  r  
------------|-----
 `a += x;`  |  r1
 a &#124;= y;  |  r2
```

and produces the following output

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace the backticks (**`**) with a `<code></code>` markup which fixes the issues more nicely by preserving the rendering

```
      a     |  r  
------------|-----
 `a += x;`  |  r1
<code>a &#124;= y;</code>  |  r2
```

generating the following output

[image]

Comment: Yeah, worked using `<code></code>` markup! Thank you very much.

Comment: Bitbucket doesn't allow `<code>`-blocks :-/ is there an other possibility?

Comment: On GitHub, the markdown escape `\|` works. People jump to HTML too fast without trying escaping the markdown.

Comment: As of March 2019, in *Gitlab* Wikis, you still need to use "`&#124;`" inside the markup code.

Comment: Still not supported by Bitbucket see https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/17106/theres-no-way-to-escape-the-pipe-character

Comment: Not supported in PyCharm :(

Comment: [mdbook](https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook) only supports the `<code></code>` solution in 2022.

Comment: In PyCharm 2022.2.4 Pro, I just used `<code>a &#124;&#124; b</code>` to do a `a || b` in a md table and it works fine in text mode and preview mode now.

Answer (score 36):

As of mid-2017, the pipe may simply be escaped with a backslash, like so: `\|`

This works both inside and outside of backticks.

The HTML code may now be used again, too, but only outside of backticks.

*Previous answer:*

> As of March 2017, the accepted answer stopped working because [GitHub
>   changed their markdown
>   parser](https://githubengineering.com/a-formal-spec-for-github-markdown/).
>   Using another unicode symbol that resembles a pipe seems to be the
>   only option right now, e.g.:
>
> ǀ (U+01C0, Latin letter dental click)
>
> ∣ (U+2223, Symbol divides)
>
> ⎮ (U+23AE, Integral Extension)

Comment: The accepted answer appears to work fine for me in GitHub, both in a Gist and in the pull request I submitted.

Answer (score 19):

You can escape the `|` in a table in GFM with a `\` like so:

```
|      a     |  r  
|------------|-----
| `a += x;`  |  r1
| `a \|= y;` |  r2
```

See https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-191 or https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/pull/743 for an example.

Comment: Thanks.  This works on Github.  Github MarkDown seems to recognize the string `\|` within a table and act accordingly.

Comment: in github, this requires a leading `|` in 1st column: this works:
```
|       a     |  r  
| ------------|-----
|  `a += x;`  |  r1
|  `a \|= y;` |  r2
```
(sorry for the formatting due to comment 1-line formatting rules)

Answer (score 3):

this works fine in github markdown:

```
|       a     |  r  
| ------------|-----
|  `a += x;`  |  r1
|  `a \|= y;` |  r2
```

very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122039/1426932 but with added `|` in first column (it didn't render well in comments so I'm adding an answer here).

note that outside a table cell, `a \|= y;` will render the backslash, but inside a table cell, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an RMarkdown / pandoc based solution with LaTeX output, the simplest solution seems to be to define a new command outside of the table, like so:

```tex
\newcommand{\pipe}{|}

|     a      |         r                  |
|------------|----------------------------|
| $a\pipe_1$ | first element of $a\pipe$  |
| $a\pipe_2$ | second element of $a\pipe$ |
```