# Convert CSV file contents to Markdown

Tags: r, csv, markdown, r-markdown, renjin

## Background

The objective is to read from a CSV file and write the contents in a Markdown table format.

The application uses the R engine [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/), which does not support [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/), [kable](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/knitr/kable.html), or [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/).

## Problem

The `write.table` command has an `eol` option, but no corresponding `sol` option. Thus for the following:

```r
f <- read.csv('planning.csv')
write.table(
   format(f, digits=2), "",
   sep="|", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, eol="|\n")
```

The output appears as follows:

```
Geothermal|1250.0|Electricity|0.0|
Houses|  13.7|Shelter|4.2|
Compostor|   1.2|Recycling|0.2|
```

But each line should appear with a `|` prefix, as follows:

```
|Geothermal|1250.0|Electricity|0.0|
|Houses|  13.7|Shelter|4.2|
|Compostor|   1.2|Recycling|0.2|
```

It should be possible to do something like (note the extra `eol` pipe):

```r
write.table(
       format(f, digits=2), "",
       sep="|", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, eol="|\n|")
```

Then capture everything as a string, concatenate a leading pipe, and finally trim the extraneous ending pipe. That is, fix the problems with the output that'll resemble:

```
Geothermal|1250.0|Electricity|0.0|
|Houses|  13.7|Shelter|4.2|
|Compostor|   1.2|Recycling|0.2|
|Fire Station|  -9.6|Protection|0.5|
|Roads|   0.0|Transport|0.9|
|
```

Such string manipulation doesn't seem very R-like, though.

## Question

What is the most efficient way to transmogrify a CSV file into a Markdown format without relying on third-party libraries?

The Markdown flavour in question looks like:

```
|Header|Header|Header|
|---|---|---|
|Data|Data|Data|
|Data|Data|Data|
```

Hints for how to write only the header data and the table header separator are also welcome.

Comment: There's [significant discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/pandoc-discuss/csv%7Csort:relevance/pandoc-discuss/znGQ62WpWrg/lFpgTPZzGgAJ) about CSV Tables on the pandoc google group, including a pandoc filter. I don't know the state of it, but you might check it out.

Comment: apply(), lapply(), sapply(), mapply(), vapply() are all functions from the base package, which is always available from within Renjin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to put it into markdown, I think it's safe to say that the table size is manageable, so performance is not a factor. (**Edit #3**: I had some small bugs relating to presence of row names, so to simplify things I'm going to remove them completely from the sample data.)

```
mtcars$rowname <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
mtcars <- mtcars[,c(ncol(mtcars), 1:(ncol(mtcars)-1))]
head(mtcars)
#             rowname  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Now the work:

```
dashes <- paste(rep("---", ncol(mtcars)), collapse = "|")
txt <- capture.output(
  write.table(mtcars, stdout(), quote = FALSE, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE)
)
txt2 <- sprintf("|%s|", c(txt[1], dashes, txt[-1]))
head(txt2)
# [1] "|rowname|mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|"  
# [2] "|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|"       
# [3] "|Mazda RX4|21|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|"         
# [4] "|Mazda RX4 Wag|21|6|160|110|3.9|2.875|17.02|0|1|4|4|"    
# [5] "|Datsun 710|22.8|4|108|93|3.85|2.32|18.61|1|1|4|1|"      
# [6] "|Hornet 4 Drive|21.4|6|258|110|3.08|3.215|19.44|1|0|3|1|"
```

If you are concerned about alignment, you can check for `character`s (and perhaps others, over to you). This uses the alignment row of the markdown table format:

```
(ischar <- vapply(mtcars, is.character, logical(1)))
# rowname     mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
#    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE 
dashes <- paste(ifelse(ischar, ":--", "--:"), collapse = "|")
txt <- capture.output(write.table(mtcars, stdout(), quote = FALSE, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE))
txt2 <- sprintf("|%s|", c(txt[1], dashes, txt[-1]))
head(txt2)
# [1] "|rowname|mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|"  
# [2] "|:--|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|"       
# [3] "|Mazda RX4|21|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|"         
# [4] "|Mazda RX4 Wag|21|6|160|110|3.9|2.875|17.02|0|1|4|4|"    
# [5] "|Datsun 710|22.8|4|108|93|3.85|2.32|18.61|1|1|4|1|"      
# [6] "|Hornet 4 Drive|21.4|6|258|110|3.08|3.215|19.44|1|0|3|1|"
```

And when you're finally ready to save, use `cat(txt2, file = "sometable.md")` (or `writeLines`).

**Edit #1**: note that the other suggested answers (including mine above) do not address pipe symbols within the content:

```
mtcars$mpg[1] <- "2|1.0"
ischar <- vapply(mtcars, is.character, logical(1))
dashes <- paste(ifelse(ischar, ":--", "--:"), collapse = "|")
txt <- capture.output(write.table(mtcars, stdout(), quote = FALSE, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE))
txt2 <- sprintf("|%s|", c(txt[1], dashes, txt[-1]))
head(txt2, n = 3)
# [1] "|rowname|mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|"
# [2] "|:--|:--|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|"     
# [3] "|Mazda RX4|2|1.0|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|"    
###                ^ this is the problem
```

You can escape it manually on all character (or add in factors, too) columns:

```
ischar <- vapply(mtcars, is.character, logical(1))
mtcars[ischar] <- lapply(mtcars[ischar], function(x) gsub("\\|", "&#124;", x))
dashes <- paste(ifelse(ischar, ":--", "--:"), collapse = "|")
txt <- capture.output(write.table(mtcars, stdout(), quote = FALSE, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE))
txt2 <- sprintf("|%s|", c(txt[1], dashes, txt[-1]))
head(txt2, n = 3)
# [1] "|rowname|mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|" 
# [2] "|:--|:--|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|"      
# [3] "|Mazda RX4|2&#124;1.0|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|"
###                ^^^^^^ this is the pipe, interpreted correctly in markdown
```

This doesn't work well when the pipe is within a code block, though a workaround was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320389/3358272

At this point, as @alistaire suggested, you're somewhat reimplementing `knitr::kable`. For that matter, just grab [`knitr/R/table.R`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/table.R)) and use `kable_markdown` which does the pipe-escaping for you. It takes a `character matrix`, not a `data.frame`, so `kable_markdown(as.matrix(mtcars))`. You can't just grab the single function as it uses several helper functions also in that file. You can certainly prune some functions, including `kable` itself which requires functions in other files.

**Edit #2**: since you said renjin doesn't support `*apply` functions (a comment suggests that is incorrect, but I'll continue for the sake of argument), here's a `for`-loop implementation that includes alignment and `|`-escaping:

```
mtcars$mpg[1] <- "2|1.0" # just a reminder that it's here
dashes <- rep("--:", length(mtcars))
for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  if (is.character(mtcars[[i]]) || is.factor(mtcars[[i]])) {
    mtcars[[i]] <- gsub("\\|", "&#124;", mtcars[[i]])
    dashes[i] <- ":--"
  }
}
txt <- capture.output(write.table(mtcars, stdout(), quote = FALSE, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE))
txt2 <- sprintf("|%s|", c(txt[1], paste(dashes, collapse = "|"), txt[-1]))
head(txt2, n = 3)
# [1] "|rowname|mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|" 
# [2] "|:--|:--|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|--:|"      
# [3] "|Mazda RX4|2&#124;1.0|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|"
```

For the record, my `*apply` and `for`-loop implementations are effectively the same performance, while @alistaire's solution is over twice as fast (with `mtcars`):

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
     apply_noalign  917.881  947.9665 1031.9288  971.3060 1041.5050 1999.499   100
       apply_align  945.960  975.1350 1083.2856  995.7390 1063.7500 3523.101   100
 apply_align_pipes 1110.429 1148.5360 1255.5460 1176.9815 1275.2600 1905.778   100
           forloop 1188.104 1217.0950 1309.2549 1261.2205 1342.3600 2979.010   100
         alistaire  451.830  473.7105  511.5778  496.1370  518.5645  827.443   100
   alistaire_pipes  593.687  626.6900  718.6898  652.7645  700.5360 5460.970   100
```

I used his original function for `alistaire` and added a simple `gsub` for `alistaire_pipes`. There may be a more efficient way to do it, but (a) simple/straight-forward is good, and (b) I think your tables will be small enough where true performance will not be a driving force.

Comment: I did not initially see the restrictions against `*apply` functions, sorry about that. I'm glad the first works. (It's actually quite straight forward to replace the `apply`s with `for` loops, if necessary.)

Comment: Your statement in **Edit #2** is incorrect: Renjin fully supports `*apply` functions. The answer provided by @alistaire, which uses the functional `Reduce()`, also works fine in Renjin. Finally, the `mtcars` data set doesn't have character columns so your use of `ischar` is superfluous here.

Comment: The OP said it, I trusted that and did not verify, my bad (I don't use renjin so do not know). I changed one column to character (3rd code block), so `ischar` is *not* superfluous overall, though I see I missed a bug in the 2nd block that would have made that clearer.

Comment: Dave Jarvis, I fixed some minor bugs (prodded by @mjkallen's comment), they may or may not be a factor in your use. Also, based on his comment, if the `*apply` functions work for you, I suggest you actually base off of one of my `apply` solutions or alistaire's function.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own version of `kable` if you like; it's mostly just `paste`.

```r
x <- read.csv(system.file('misc', 'exDIF.csv', package = 'utils'))

md_table <- function(df){
    paste0('|', paste(names(df), collapse = '|'), '|\n|', 
           paste(rep('---', length(df)), collapse = '|'), '|\n|', 
           paste(Reduce(function(x, y){paste(x, y, sep = '|')}, df), collapse = '|\n|'), '|')
}

cat(md_table(x))
#> |Var1|Var2|
#> |---|---|
#> |2.7|A|
#> |3.14|B|
#> |10|A|
#> |-7|A|

cat(md_table(head(mtcars)))
#> |mpg|cyl|disp|hp|drat|wt|qsec|vs|am|gear|carb|
#> |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
#> |21|6|160|110|3.9|2.62|16.46|0|1|4|4|
#> |21|6|160|110|3.9|2.875|17.02|0|1|4|4|
#> |22.8|4|108|93|3.85|2.32|18.61|1|1|4|1|
#> |21.4|6|258|110|3.08|3.215|19.44|1|0|3|1|
#> |18.7|8|360|175|3.15|3.44|17.02|0|0|3|2|
#> |18.1|6|225|105|2.76|3.46|20.22|1|0|3|1|
```

Rewrite the second line to handle justification based on type if you like.