# Stop Gist MarkDown characters from interfering with one another?

Tags: javascript, github, markdown, gist

I am using Gist to publish a page in MarkDown about JavaScript operators. Within my document I am building a table, however I want to include characters in my table that interfere with the pages MarkDown syntax.

This is a portion of my table is MarkDown

```
| Syntax      | Type           |
|     ---     |:    ---       :|
|    a | b    |   Bitwise OR   |
|    a && b   |   Logical AND  |
|    a || b   |   Logical OR   |
```

As you can see, because the table is including the character '|' within its contents, MarkDown thinks this is part of the table and formats it incorrectly. How can I avoid this formatting issue?

I have tempted to wrap the content in HTML comments tags `<!-- -->` and `<p></p>` tags both to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a pipe char in a code statement in a markdown table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319940/how-to-escape-a-pipe-char-in-a-code-statement-in-a-markdown-table)

Comment: It does seem to be, I did search but did not manage to use the correct wording to find that answer. I have selected @DarthJDG answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the backslash character to escape the pipes within the cell's text.

```
| Syntax      | Type           |
|-------------|:--------------:|
| a \| b      |   Bitwise OR   |
| a && b      |   Logical AND  |
| a \|\| b    |   Logical OR   |
```