# Trouble escaping RegEx pipes inside a markdown table to be posted in a GitLab wiki

Tags: regex, gitlab, markdown

## What I've Tried

Markdown tables on GitLab (as far as I can tell) require me to use a pipe (|) as a delimiter. The problem is that the regular expression I need to use also has pipes so they need escaping, which I believe is done using a backslash like this `\|`.

So, the original regex is...

```
^123\.123\.(1(7[2-3]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

And here is the escaped regex...

```
^123\.123\.(1(7[2-3]))\.([0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\|1([0-9][0-9])\|2([0-4][0-9]\|5[0-5]))$
```

Finally, here is the escaped regex in my markdown table...

```
IP Block         | RegEx
---------------- | ----------------
123.123.172.0/23 | ^123\.123\.(1(7[2-3]))\.([0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\|1([0-9][0-9])\|2([0-4][0-9]\|5[0-5]))$
```

## The Problem

For some reason GitLab is still terminating my table cell at the first pipe in my regex even though it is escaped.

- Did I escape it wrong?
- Is there something else in the regex that is causing markdown to fail?

Comment: Yeah... here's what ended up working. I needed to escape first `^` with a backslash and used `&#124;` in place of the pipes like this: `\^123\.123\.(1(7[2-3]))\.([0-9]&#124;[1-9][0-9]&#124;1([0-9][0-9])&#124;2([0-4][0-9]&#124;5[0-5]))$`.

Comment: replacing pipes with `&#124;` sadly doesn't work if the text is surrounded by backticks, and pipe unicodes won't be renderd.

Comment: duplicate: [How to escape a pipe char in a code statement in a markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17319940/104380)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape a pipe char in a code statement in a markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319940/how-to-escape-a-pipe-char-in-a-code-statement-in-a-markdown-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what ended up working. I needed to escape first ^ with a backslash and used | in place of the pipes like this...

```
\^123\.123\.(1(7[2-3]))\.([0-9]&#124;[1-9][0-9]&#124;1([0-9][0-9])&#124;2([0-4][0-9]&#124;5[0-5]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Arround your regex :

- use `<pre>` *your_regex* `</pre>` HTML tag
- or use ``` to escape code.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/

Comment: I tried what you suggested in GitLab and adding wrapping `<pre>` tags or code block marks `\`\`\`` around that problem regex didn't work.