# Vertical bar symbol within a markdown table

Tags: escaping, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, docusaurus

Markdown tables use vertical bars as field separators, but I need to write a vertical bar within some cells. Is this possible? I'm using GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown).

Can I escape the vertical bar somehow?

This is not on GitHub, it's through Docusaurus. I don't know which parser Docusaurus uses, but none of the following work:

- `&#124;` - `&#124;` just gets displayed (the `&` is escaped)
- `<code>` - Any html is displayed (the `<` is escaped)
- `\|` - `|` still acts as a table cell delimiter

***UPDATE***:

`&#124;` works if I don't have it inside backticks. So, at least for now, I simply un-backtick the vertical bar. For example, `a | b` becomes `a`|`b`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a pipe char in a code statement in a markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319940/how-to-escape-a-pipe-char-in-a-code-statement-in-a-markdown-table)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here! Docusaurus uses Remarkable for parsing Markdown.

As you pointed out in your question, you can write this in your table - `&#124;` and it will render as `|`.

If you want it to appear with monospaced styling, wrap it in `<code>&#124;</code>` instead of using backticks. You will have to write HTML and not markdown to get it to work.

Refer to line 30 of [Reason Cheatsheet](https://github.com/reasonml/reasonml.github.io/blob/source/docs/syntax-cheatsheet.md).  I recently fixed a similar issue in the Reason docs.

```
## Boolean

| JavaScript                                            | Reason                                         |
| ----------------------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| `true`, `false`                                       | `true`, `false` \*                             |
| `!true`                                               | Same                                           |
| <code>&#124;&#124;</code>, `&&`, `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>` | Same                                           |
| `a === b`, `a !== b`                                  | Same                                           |
| No deep equality (recursive compare)                  | `a == b`, `a != b`                             |
| `a == b`                                              | No equality with implicit casting (thankfully) |
```

becomes:

[image: Reason Table]

Comment: Thank you @Yangshun! But I had already tried `<code>`. Docusaurus (apparently Remarkable) just displays `<code>whatever I type here</code>`, angled brackets and all.

Comment: @at Do you have a repository on GitHub I can look at? Would be easier to help you debug there. Let me know which file and line you want to achieve it.

Comment: that would be so helpful!
The GitHub repo: https://github.com/ucode/udocs/blob/master/docs/order_of_operations.md
The specific page I had some `|`s: https://github.com/ucode/udocs/blob/master/docs/order_of_operations.md
The resulting page generated from Docusaurus: https://www.udocs.com/docs/order_of_operations.html

Comment: @at Have made a pull request to your repo 

Comment: Thank you @Yangshun. It seems `<code>` did work. Strange, I tried `<code>` before and the parsed result escaped the `<` character so `<code>` was displayed in the HTML. Maybe I did it inside of backticks or some other mechanism that Remarkable wouldn't parse the expected way...

Comment: I think that might have been the case. Good that it's resolved! (:

Answer (score 4):

If the usual strategies won't work you should be able to use a Unicode character that looks like a bar, but isn't, e.g. [`⎮` Unicode Character 'INTEGRAL EXTENSION' (U+23AE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ae/index.htm):

```
| foo   | bar |
| ----- | --- |
| `a⎮b` | baz |
```

Comment: This would be a problem if people copy the code out from the webpage and paste it in their editor. They will get hard-to-debug compilation errors.

Comment: @YangshunTay, that's true if the content is literal code, i.e. something that a person would ever want to copy into a code editor. I may have misunderstood, but I thought the content in question was meant for human consumption only.

Comment: In any case, the `<code>` option is much better than my answer if it works. OP's question said it didn't, but I'll defer to the maintainer :-).

Answer (score 4):

If you are typing math and $p(x|y)$ breaks the formula, use \vert instead of |.