# Display pipe in table in jupyter notebook on Github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I uploaded a table in a Jupyter notebook (ipynb file). The table contains some pipes '|', and it is in a markdown-formatted cell of course. It looks normal on my local Jupyter notebook:

[image]

The codes for the table are:

```
||**hash table**|**direct-address table**|
|:-|:--------------:|:------------------------:|
|Storage requirement|$\Theta(|K|)$|$|U|$|
|Search time| $O(1)$ time for *average-case*|$O(1)$ time for *worst-case*|
|Location of an element with key $k$|slot $h(k)$|slot $k$|
```

However, it seems to be a problem when I open it after uploading to Github (I suspect errors with the '|' symbol):

[image]

The center alignment also failed.

I apologise if the question has been asked before, but I tried other answers on SO: [escape-pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319940/how-to-escape-a-pipe-char-in-a-code-statement-in-a-markdown-table). Unfortunately, the `\|` they recommended did not work. The link to the GitHub page is: [this one](https://github.com/tianlinhe/CLRS-in-Python/blob/master/11.Hash_Tables/11.2_Hash_tables.ipynb), where you can see the edited full codes.

Could anyone help? I am rather new in Github and Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the linked answer on the question, **the answer in the linked question is incorrect**, look at the comments there!

> As of March 2019, in Gitlab Wikis, you still need to use "`&#124;`" inside the markup code. – knb Mar 22 '19 at 13:52

You should use `&#124;`.

If you do not like the jumble of characters, use this!

> (Although it technically is a different character, you can still use it! [Its width is higher because it is a full-width character.])

Full-width character: enter `｜` in your keyboard, and it shows `｜`. (note the extra width as a different character)
Normal pipe: enter `&#124;`, and this shows `|`, live  example:"|".

### Recommendation:

You should use the `&#124;` method, as the character is exactly the same as you wanted, and not a different variant of the character.

Comment: Thanks! I will try later and let you know!

Comment: @tianlinhe: Also, your github pages link returns a 404 from github, BTW.

Comment: Sorry, it is [this one](https://github.com/tianlinhe/CLRS-in-Python/blob/master/11.Hash_Tables/11.2_Hash_tables.ipynb). I will update the question too!

Comment: @tianlinhe Now that I see your file, I'm not sure if it'll work, as it is not a markdown file, atleast not one with a .md extension

Comment: @TheUnchOsenOne yes unfortunately. It is a markdown cell inside ipynb, which can be displayed normally on jupyter notebook, but not on Github. Somehow the file does not render now on my PC, if you don't mind, you may submit a pull request and see if the correction solves the problem?

Comment: @tianlinhe ***Are you sure it didn't work?***, it worked for be. (the resolution in the answer.)

Comment: Great thanks, I merge it! Although the alignment problem still persists, but I am so happy that the pipes are at least displayed properly!

Comment: @tianlinhe Hmm... what alignment problem? edit: i found out now

Answer (score 1):

### On the Alignment of the text in the table:

I *personally think* that is *impossible*:

Well, the problem is on Github and Html5 *itself*.
Github doesn't allow ANY style OR script, so editing the page with DOM, or using style is no use.

Html5 does not support the align attribute OR the center tag.
And Github has a bad bug in it's ipynb rendering engine, so be ready to say *bye bye* to aligning text in iphnb files!

Also take a look on [this github issue](https://github.com/iurisegtovich/PyTherm-applied-thermodynamics/issues/11) which hints that using ipynb files on github are not as good as you think!